# javascript validation works unpredictably

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have the code

```
        $(".jqte_editor").keyup( function(){
        console.log($(this).text().trim());
        $(this).parent().find(".validationmessagecomposed").remove();
        if(!/^.{100,}$/g.test($(this).text()))
        {
            displayvalidationmessage($(this), "Please enter some more content");
        }

    });
```

and it fails on the string

```
    <div><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family:
    'Courier New', Courier, monospace; white-space: pre-wrap;">
    Install</span><br></div><div><pre style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">    How to install HTML Purifier

   HTML Purifier is designed to run out of the box, so actually using the
   library is extremely easy.  (Although... if you were looking for a
   step-by-step installation GUI, you've downloaded the wrong software!)
   </pre></div>
```

while it passes other text.. not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: Is that a newline after "How to install HTML Purifier"?

Comment: @Cruiser oh.. yes... I figured it out.. the `.` is not matching the newlines.. so i changed the `.` to [\s\S] .. now it works.. i did not know that wild card will fail ...

Comment: Yeah, the . doesn't match newline characters, but it was hard to tell if it was a newline there or not.